# Only one co-supervisor is supervising, but my project is in other co-supervisor's field

Tags: phd, united-states, engineering, electrical-engineering

I'm currently a PhD student at a US-based university in electrical engineering.

I started my PhD in 2021 with co-supervisors A1 and B1. However, I found working with A1 and B1 to be very difficult due to severe personality conflicts. Therefore, I pushed through until the end of my first year, submitted a paper with them, and then left them to move to a new pair of co-supervisors A2 and B2.

Before I started working with A2 and B2 in 2022, I was told by A2 and B2 that the project that I will be working on with them consisted of a mix of theory from field A and field B, and that A2 will provide advice on field A and B2 will provide advice on field B, which are their respective specializations.

It is now 2024, and what happened in practice is very different. First, the project that was supposed to be a mix of field A and field B turned out to only involve field B, with no involvement of field A whatsoever.

Second, over the past two years, supervisor B2, who is specialized in field B, was not involved in the research at all. They would not read any of the papers, they would mostly ignore my emails to them asking for advice, and when I was eventually able to ask them for advice, they told me to go talk to another faculty member in the department because they themselves cannot help me.

Instead, supervisor A2 decided to take over supervisor B2's role as an adviser for field B, which is not their specialization. This, however, had disastrous consequences from my perspective. Supervisor A2 would consistently provide incorrect information regarding basic facts in field B, and I had to correct them every time.

Moreover, supervisor A2 would consistently not trust me when I told them that something in field B that they are proposing would not work, even after providing a formal mathematical proof.

At this point, I had studied field B for two years to be able to perform the research myself without any guidance from supervisor B2, so I had some level of experience in this field. I would go back-and-forth with them over email over several days explaining why something would not work, and even when I do try it after giving up, it still wouldn't work as I previously said.

At this point, it has been 2 years and we have not published a single conference or journal paper. In my department, this is rare at the PhD level. Additionally, supervisor A2 has very little experience publishing papers in field B, which is the field that this project is in.

Therefore, I see the following three options ahead of me (feel free to suggest others):

1. **Cut my losses**: I cut my losses and try to find a new single supervisor (not a pair of co-advisers like my previous two experiences). Also, my two experiences so far with PhD co-supervisors has been with tenured professors, and I suspect that this is the source of the problem. I will also try to find a young assistant professor to join who is eager to publish and will need to graduate PhD students, unlike tenured professors.
2. **Stick with it**: My funding from the department ends in 2026, but can be extended on request. The initial plan in 2022 was that I would spend at most 4 years with supervisors A2 and B2 before graduating in 2026. However, it does not look like I will graduate in 2026 based on the slow progress so far. To be honest, from my perspective, we could easily spend another year on this project without making any progress whatsoever.
3. **Bring on another co-supervisor**: I previously requested from my co-supervisors to bring on a third supervisor who specializes in field B. However, supervisor A2 rejected this idea, saying that having three co-supervisors is "unusual".

I would prefer option (1), but at the moment, there are no suitable professors that I can join. However, my department will hire 1 assistant professor in field B next semester, so there is a chance that I can join them next semester. Option (2) if my least preferred, since I'm also starting to get exhausted from continuing to work with supervisor A2, which is affecting me mentally.

Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but I'm still in my first year. My supervisor suggested a research topic he didn't know much about, so I got minimal help from him, but had to explain to him why it didn't work instead. When I discussed my idea with him, he simply said it wasn't worth publishing.

Comment: @JackBlack Thank you for sharing this. Unfortunately, I tried this with my co-adviser, but they didn’t agree.